# How to extract a path in text file and use it in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, tex

as a beginner , i have been with this problem 2 days and i am desperate for your help .

My text file is :

```
C:\Sourcefile\imported
C:\Destination\not imported
C:\Testexcel\test.xlxs
```

and i need to read the text and use these path in vba .
The object of the vba code is to create a new folder if it not existe in the destination .

```
FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oSourceFolder=FSO.getfolder(Line1,Readline)  'if i replace line with the path it will work
set oSourceFolder=FSO.getfolder(Line2,Readline)
set oSourceFolder=FSO.getfolder(Line3,Readline)

if dir("C:\Destination\not imported",16)="" Then Mkdir (":\Destination\not imported")
```

Here , i want to replace the path with the line but it is not working .

Can you help me please ?

Comment: FSO.FolderExists and FSO.CreateFolder will help.  Set the a file object and then get the path from that object also may assist.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes but i dont have a problem in that , the problem is that i do not know how to use the text file and it there path to vba

Comment: Also check this link..    http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm

Comment: Look at what you have available in the filesystemobject.  ie. File object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must

- add `Set` keyword at the beginning of

`FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"`)

- use [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278803.aspx) method of [TextStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278803.aspx) object to retrieve every single line of the text file into a `string` object
- parse that `string` returned for possible files specification and get only their its *path* part
- use [FolderExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251645.aspx) method of FileSystemObject object to check for existing folders
- and finally get (if existent) that folder or create (if non existent) it via [GetFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278492.aspx) or [CreateFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251706.aspx) methods of FileSystemObject object

much like follows:

---

```
     Option Explicit

     Sub main()
        Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
        Dim foldersListFile As TextStream
        Dim folderName As String
        Dim oSourceFolder As Folder

        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        Set foldersListFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\myPath\folders.txt", ForReading, TristateFalse)

        Do While Not foldersListFile.AtEndOfStream
             folderName = GetFolderStringOnly(foldersListFile.ReadLine)

             If FSO.FolderExists(folderName) Then
                 Set oSourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(folderName)
             Else
                 Set oSourceFolder = FSO.CreateFolder(folderName)
             End If
           Loop

        foldersListFile.Close

     End Sub

     Function GetFolderStringOnly(textLine As String) As String
         Dim iDot As Long, iSlash As Long
         iDot = InStrRev(textLine, ".")
         If iDot > 0 Then
             iSlash = InStrRev(Left(textLine, iDot), "\")
             textLine = Left(textLine, iSlash - 1)
         End If
         GetFolderStringOnly = textLine
     End Function
```

Comment: i just wan to ask you , how can i specify which line should vba will read to extract the path of the txt file? Thank you

Comment: you can count the lines in the `Do While - Loop` block and stop when reaching the wanted line. to do that add in some `Dim countLine as long` at the beginning and a `countLine = countLine +1` inside the loop

Comment: Did you get though it?

Comment: you're welcome. if my answer fulfilled your question please mark it as accepted. if it also proved useful you may want to up-vote it. thank you